# CMB2 Group field data doesn't get imported by WordPress Importer

Tags: wordpress, import

I am developing a WordPress theme and using CMB2 for Metaboxes. Facing a problem to import the meta data (field type: group and repeatable) via WordPress Importer.

I've total 8 group fields and 2 of them isn't importing properly. Rest others are getting imported fine.

Any idea about why this happen? I need to fix it for preparing the demo data.
How can i resolve it?

These fields are saved as serialized data.

I am using the [wordpress-importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/)! plugin for importing demo data.

[Here is a sample of exported meta data for a post. But it's not getting imported via WordPress Importer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBa72.png)

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: I am using the https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/ plugin for importing. No custom codes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why, but importers serialize twice the group field value in postmeta table...

For my part, I unserialize "manually" (...with a little script) the meta_value returned by :

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` where meta_value like 's:%' AND meta_key IN ('my_identification_group', 'my_other_identification_group')
```